# How AZURE Service Bus rules with messages on subscription?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I don't get it.

Say I have one queve, one topic, one subscroption. And three clients that subscribe on that.

I send a message.

First client recieve a message and call complete() action.

Will second client recieve a message?

What if there will forth client, who subscribe on it?

Question is - when will message completely remove from queve/topic/subscription??

P.S. Case when "one-to-one" - is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check out the Competing Consumers pattern. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568101.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can have many roles (i.e. Azure Worker Role) checking for messages in a queue (competing consumers), locking them exclusively while processing. Each role is fighting for a message, and the first guy who grabs it (by chance), has it "exclusive" for the moment. If the consumer that gets and processes the message succeeds, run the Complete() method, otherwise the Abandon(message). Complete() finishes it for good, and Abandon throws it back into the frenzy of competing consumers. You can even grab it again if you're healthy!

You can set the dead message parameter in the Azure Management Portal which determines how many times it can be reintroduced for other consumers. At some point, things just aren't working, so kill the message so other messages can resume unimpeded.

Let me know if you have more specific needs. Would be happy to help. This pattern works extremely well.

Kindest regards...